# Is "a fresh pair of eyes" necessarily somebody else?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I would like to describe a person who returns from a mind-relaxing break back to work by the idiom "fresh pair of eyes". However, as per its definition on some sources, "a fresh pair of eyes" is "another person [...]", which made me think that maybe it is not suitable.

The situation I am imagining is of a person who worked longer than he/she expected to find the evident (by the incorrect outcome) mistake in his/her work, goes out for a break, then returns back to examine his work again for the mistake. I would like to describe the property of this man/lady being refreshed by the break, and in a concise and effective manner.

Does the idiom "a fresh pair of eyes" fit into this description? If not, then what else should be my phrase of choice?

Comment: I would still say it needs to be another person primarily because the original person still has seen his/her work already. I've always used "fresh set of eyes" to describe eyes that have never seen the subject. I would recommend maybe "a fresh perspective" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can take a break so that they return with a fresh pair of eyes, or so that they review the work with a fresh pair of eyes. However, the phrase idiomatically refers to getting someone else to have a look - someone whose preconceptions or perspectives haven't already been tamed to match that of those close to the project.

> Fig. another person to examine something closely in addition to anyone previously. *As soon as we can get a fresh pair of eyes on this mansuscipt, we will find the last of the typos.*
>   [- The free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+fresh+pair+of+eyes)

Comment: Should I perhaps than say "*almost* fresh pair of eyes", or just use it without the "almost" regardless of what it idiomatically refers to?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin No, I don't think *almost* gets you what you want here. The phrase (and in particular the word "fresh") *can* be used in its literal sense, as noted in the opening sentence of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say not necessarily.

When I review my work after a 'transforming experience' (a break, a holiday, a profound discussion...) it is frequently the case that *I can see my own work with a **fresh**  pair of eyes*.

***Fresh*** - *Not exhausted or fatigued; full of vigour and energy; brisk, vigorous, active*' (OED).